# NativeScript sampleGroceries app does not compile

Tags: android, node.js, nativescript

I started to learn nativescript and trying to follow guide on the main site. But when im trying to compile this helloworld application with `tns run android --emulator` my shell getting stuck on 
 `Building 54% > :mergeF0DebugResources`

here is the full output http://pastebin.com/djyzRZHk

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like there is a mismatch between the android sdk and the tns platform. Remove the platforms/android directory completely, make sure that your android sdk is properly up to date and then try again.
Also, try running aapt on it's own and see if there are errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Log says:

`Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/kirill/Загрузки/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds`

It suggest it is anti-virus, also suggest a solution:
Setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds